# How do I analyze music using C?

Tags: audio

I am looking to analyze a given piece of music using C, reading from mp3 files, and outputs the tempo, pitch, key etc.

Is there an open source project already written for this or a way to just program it myself? I tried PortAudio, but it did not look correct for the test.

Answer (score 1):

Mabe [aubio](http://aubio.org) (written in C) or [Essentia](http://essentia.upf.edu) (written in C++) fit your needs?